# Variable = 0 when JFrame window is close

Tags: java, jframe

I created a chatbot, but when i close it, i need a variable = 0, so that the chatbot can be opened again but it cannot be opened twice (for example when it is already open).

My code:

```
public ChatBot() {
    //Creo i frame
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setSize(600, 600);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setResizable(false);
     
    //Titolo chat
    this.setTitle("ChatBot");
```

how can i reset the variable when jframe is dispose on close?

Comment: You could add a on close listener.

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: You should almost never have any more than one ```JFrame```. So the ```JFrame``` controlling the chatbot will already be open (or you couldn't take any action). Make the chatbot a singleton of type ```JDialog```

Comment: This is the first time I use jframe, can you explain to me how to do it?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/windowlistener.html

Comment: Ok thanks, but how i can control if the JFrame is open?

Comment: I use a button, and every time i click the button, a new JFrame is open...